# Como agendar tarefas para um determinado horário C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Preciso de método para executar tarefas todo dia no mesmo horário qual classe devo usar para esse tipo de tarefa?

Comment: Você poderia usar as bibliotecas https://www.hangfire.io/ ou https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ para fazer isso, elas servem para configurar rotinas no seu sistema para serem executadas em determinados horarios programados

Comment: @Randrade esta pergunta não é uma duplicata da indicada. Esta é sobre ASP.NET, a outra é sobre .NET em geral. A forma de se agendar a execução de uma tarefa é diferente quando você usa ASP.NET.

Comment: Talvez esse artigo possa ser util. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: @Renan A pergunta pode estar utilizando tags diferentes, mas creio que as respostas serão parecidas, se não as mesmas.

Comment: @Randrade não serão, pois são dois ambientes completamente diferentes. O que funciona para Windows Forms e serviços Windows não funciona para ASP.NET.

Comment: @Renan As três respostas podem ser adequadas à pergunta. A diferença é que uma fala explicitamente de `Windows Services`, que necessita criar algo a mais, mas não excludente. Todavia, as outras respostas mostram formas que funcionam tanto para WinForms quanto para Asp.Net MVC, Web API e até mesmo para  .NET Core.

Comment: Precisa ser em um horário específico todos os dias (ex: todo dia às 4h da manhã) ou tanto faz o horário, desde que seja no mesmo horário todos os dias (ex: se a aplicação iniciou às 13:37, que seja todo dia esse mesmo horário)? Enfim, eu particularmente utilizo o [Fluent Scheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler), acho ele mais prático do que os demais, além de ser open source. Mas acredito que ambas situações também podem ser feitas com os demais citados.

Comment: @Alisson Horário específico